# How to move from a physical server to an online server?

Tags: cloud-hosting, windows-server-2008

My father has a small company: 10 PCs running Windows, 1 running Windows Server 2000 and 1 Fax/Printer.

I want to remove the server and make the network based on an Online server. Can I do that? If yes, how? By using a Windows VPS? Linux VPS with VMWaRE? I'm not sure if that's a viable option, if there's other, please tell me.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using the server as a local network server (File shares, Exchange, SQL Server, Domain Controller, etc), you should not move it to the cloud.

These servers should be as close as possible to the clients in the network to optimize response time, so moving it to the cloud will make things much slower.

In addition, these servers should usually not be internet-facing (except a mail server)

Comment: +1, Accounting software counts as a file server (probably, or has financial info that you probably don't want the hosting company to have custody of). Hosted e-mail services are good, but a local server is faster.

Comment: +1 I don't think it can be uderstated how really really dangerous  and potentially expensive this idea is.

Comment: +1 - anoter case of incompetent advice "bettering" a business, potentially into oblivion ;)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The server is only used for Email, Backups, Fax and an Accounting software. Just that, very simple. If it wasn't for the Accounting software, I would move to a Linux VPS.

What I want to understand is: Can I still use the online server/VPS to do the same thing as the physical server? If yes, what should I learn first?

BR

Comment: I need to answer here, I'm sorry.
What if I don't have any other option? What if I need to go for the online server?

Comment: You should associate your accounts.

Comment: Yes, you can, but you shouldn't.

Comment: What do you recommend? I was thinking about Rackspace Cloud Windows? Thanks for your honesty.

Comment: Any help in how to do it? Something to read? Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity why would you want to do this?

Comment: plus - how would you smartly replace the fax server? Ignoring reality. Not a good start.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are determined to move to the cloud. I hate to advertise, but here is what happened. I moved one of our backup servers to the **[Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)** and it was pretty much easy as setting up a local server. It just took some time to understand the instances, images and elastic IP. But once done, everything worked like charm. I have not used rackspace, so don't know what advantages you get over the other.

Comment: the big difference is that rackspace can guarantee availablity and resource performance